# Tableau Desktop Connection to Tableau Server ..Data Source

Tags: tableau-api

I able to connect to Tableau Server using Tableau Desktop 2020.2.7 and cannot see data in "Search for data ". I am planning to run a performance recorder for one Dashboard. Please advise what has to be done to see the dashboard.

Note: I am able to access all dashboards when I log in using the Tableau server using the URL through the browser.

Comment: Contact your admin. Permissions for dashboards differ from permissions to data sources.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to seek elevated permissions in order to connect Tableau Desktop to Tableau Server. In the case that you intend to develop locally and be able to publish (and overwrite) you would need the access level of:

> 'Explorer (can publish)'

Yes, it appears whilst you have 'Viewer' access that enables you to you access dashboards via the URL in the browser, you won't be able to connect Tableau Desktop nor be able to download the workbook as a file either (only summary data).

[See Permission and Roles](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/permission_license_siterole.htm)

Namely what each of the capabilities are under different scenarios (matrix table)
[image: Permission and Roles]